# std::bind on a generic lambda - auto type deduction

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    auto run = [](auto&& f, auto&& arg) {
        f(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
    };
    auto foo = [](int &x) {};
    int var;
    auto run_foo = std::bind(run, foo, var);
    run_foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following compilation error when compiled with clang:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 my_test.cpp

my_test.cpp:6:9: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const (lambda at my_test.cpp:8:16)'
        f(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/functional:998:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'main()::(anonymous class)::operator()<const (lambda at my_test.cpp:8:16) &, const int &>' requested here
        = decltype( std::declval<typename enable_if<(sizeof...(_Args) >= 0),
                    ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../include/c++/6.3.1/functional:1003:2: note: in instantiation of default argument for 'operator()<>' required here
        operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
my_test.cpp:11:12: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator()' [with _Args = <>, _Result = (no value)]
    run_foo();
           ^
my_test.cpp:8:16: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const int') would lose const qualifier
    auto foo = [](int &x) {};
               ^
my_test.cpp:8:16: note: conversion candidate of type 'void (*)(int &)'
1 error generated.
```

Why is `arg` deduced to be `const int&` instead of just `int&`?

std::bind [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) says:

> Given an object g obtained from an earlier call to bind, when it is
>   invoked in a function call expression g(u1, u2, ... uM), an invocation
>   of the stored object takes place, as if by std::invoke(fd,
>   std::forward(v1), std::forward(v2), ...,
>   std::forward(vN)), where fd is a value of type std::decay_t the
>   values and types of the bound arguments v1, v2, ..., vN are determined
>   as specified below.
>
> ...
>
> **Otherwise, the
>   ordinary stored argument arg is passed to the invokable object as
>   lvalue argument: the argument vn in the std::invoke call above is
>   simply arg and the corresponding type Vn is T cv &, where cv is the
>   same cv-qualification as that of g.**

But in this case, `run_foo` is **cv-unqualified**. What am I missing?

Comment: If it helps, `arg` is deduced to `int`, but because `operator()` is `const`, the stored `var` is `const`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 If I'm not mistaken, there's an unqualified version of `operator()`, and the `const` version is called when `*this` is `const`, which makes it even weirder.

Comment: In my implementation I can only see `operator() const`, but yeah, it's weird.

Comment: Template argument deduction and substitution happens before overload resolution, so even if `operator() const` will not be selected by overload resolution, substitution still happens. In this case, substitution failure does not appear in the immediate context, so this substitution failure _is_ a hard error.

Comment: @cpplearner That'd make a good answer from the implementation's perspective, but the standard just says the effect of `run_foo()` is `run(foo, var)`, doesn't it? I don't see where it says "unless the invocation `as_const(run)(as_const(foo), as_const(var))` would be ill-formed" or anything like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MWE:

```
#include <functional>

int main() {
    int i;
    std::bind([] (auto& x) {x = 1;}, i)();
}
```

[[func.bind]/(10.4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.bind.bind#10) states that the cv-qualifiers of the argument passed to the lambda are those of the argument to `bind`, augmented by the cv-qualifiers of the call wrapper; but there are none, and thus a non-`const` `int` should be passed in.

Both libc++ and libstdc++ fail to resolve the call. For libc++, reported as [#32856](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32856), libstdc++ as [#80564](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80564). The main problem is that both libraries infer the return type in the signature somehow, looking like this for libstdc++:

```
  // Call as const
template<typename... _Args, typename _Result
  = decltype( std::declval<typename enable_if<(sizeof...(_Args) >= 0),
           typename add_const<_Functor>::type&>::type>()(
               _Mu<_Bound_args>()( std::declval<const _Bound_args&>(),
                                   std::declval<tuple<_Args...>&>() )... ) )>
_Result operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
```

During template argument deduction as necessitated by overload resolution, the default template argument will be instantiated, which causes a hard error due to our ill-formed assignment inside the closure.

This can be fixed by perhaps a deduced placeholder: remove `_Result` and its default argument entirely, and declare the return type as `decltype(auto)`. This way, we also get rid of SFINAE which influences overload resolution and thereby induces incorrect behaviour:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
  template <typename T>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<T>{}> operator()(T&) const;
};

int main() {
    int i;
    std::bind(A{}, i)();
}
```

This should not compile—as explained above, the argument passed to  `A::operator()` should be non-`const` because `i` and the forwarding call wrapper are. However, again, this compiles under libc++ and libstdc++, because their `operator()`s fall back on `const` versions after the non-`const` ones fail under SFINAE.